# Laravel - Acess config() from inside config/mail.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a table where I store all my configs...

Service provider:

```
class SettingsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Factory $cache, SettingRepository $settings)
    {
        if(Schema::hasTable('settings')){
            $settings = $cache->remember('settings', 60, function() use ($settings)
            {
                return $settings->lists();
            });

            config()->set('settings', $settings);
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            \App\Repositories\SettingRepository::class
        );
    }
}
```

Service repository:

```
class SettingRepository{
    private $settings;

    public function __construct(Setting $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function update($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            foreach ($key as $name => $value)
            {
                $this->update($name, $value);
            }

            return;
        }

        $setting = $this->settings->firstOrCreate(['name' => $key]);
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }

    public function lists()
    {
        return $this->settings->lists('value', 'name')->all();
    }
}
```

However when I try to use `config()` within the config/mail.php file is returned a null value.

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the config files are loaded before your ServiceProvider is loaded.

What you could do instead is save your settings with the 'full' key (name in your table) in the database e.g. `mail.from.address` and overwrite them.

```php
// Example data returned from SettingsRepository->lists()
$settigs = [
    // Mail config you might want to overwrite
    'mail.from.address' => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'mail.from.name' => 'John Doe',

    // Other settings 
    'settings.something' =>  'foo',
    'settings.else' => 'bar',
];

config()->set($settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing where you're calling `config()` and how in config/mail.php I can only guess.. but you should be able to use `config()` in config/mail.php

What are you calling? If you dd(config()); at the top of config/mail.php you see all of your configuration variables. If it returns a `null` value, it's because that configuration value doesn't exist.

You may also need a config/settings.php which is being loaded in your Service Provider's `register()` method?

```
public function register()
{
    config([
        'config/myfile.php',
    ]);
}
```

see: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ho-to-access-config-variables-in-laravel-5/replies/25075